# how to show inside foreach value upper than loop in php

Tags: php, foreach

I have a problem to show an inside foreach value upper than a loop.how Can I show this value?

I have tried this but it's not working please give any suggestions.

```
<?php echo $ph_no = '' ?>

<?php 
        foreach ($saloon_earning as $key => $value): 

        $ph_no = $value->phone_number;  
    ?>

<?php echo $value->total_amount ?>

<?php echo $value->price_per_installment ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Array format:-

```
Array
(
    [saloon_earning] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [users_id] => 1
                    [date] => 2018-01-13
                    [saloon_profiles_id] => 2
                    [appointments_id] => 1
                    [price_per_installment] => 58
                    [total_amount] => 81
                    [phone_number] => 982382
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: any error you are facing?

Comment: what do you want exactly ? and what is the error showing ?

Comment: can you please explain more

Comment: `I have a problem to show a inside foreach value upper than loop.`-> what upper value you are talking about? You question is completely unclear

Comment: I am not facing any error but it's not show the value of phone number which i want to show upper than loop

Comment: If remove quotes from $ph_no = ' ' than it give me undifine variable error

Comment: What do you mean upper than loop  ???

Comment: <?php echo $ph_no = ' ' ?> I want to show phone_number upper than foreach but it's not showing

Comment: `<?php echo $ph_no = '' ?>` need to be `<?php echo $ph_no = ''; ?>` and since this is empty how can it will show any value and if you are thinking that `foreach()` values are going to update inside it, Not possible(if it's upside `foreach()`, you have to put it `down`)

Comment: Yes I know the value will be shown in the loop but here is the scenario that I want to show up than loop

Comment: what is in your array $saloon_earning ? can you please print it ?

Comment: Not possible at all. And are you want to show all value or only single values for the array in upeer phone number?

Comment: Only single value

Comment: what is format of your array $saloon_earning ?

Comment: I have edited the question please see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i think you want to show first phone value without loop, do like below:-

```
<?php echo $ph_no = $saloon_earning[0]->phone_number; ?>

<?php 
  foreach ($saloon_earning as $key => $value): 
     if($key>0){
        $ph_no = $value->phone_number; 
     }
?>

<?php echo $value->total_amount ?>

<?php echo $value->price_per_installment ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php 
    foreach ($saloon_earning as $key => $value)
    {
        $ph_no = $value->phone_number;  
    }
?>
```